# Slicing a multidimensional numpy array -> 3D point clusters at different time instances

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy-array, who's shape is:

```
(30,40,100,200)
```

Those are 3D points (30(x-axis)x40(y-axis)x100(z-axis)) for different times (200 in total):

[image]

For visualization only (this is not my dataset, the picture comes from here: *http://15462.courses.cs.cmu.edu/fall2016/article/35)*

Now, I have issues with understanding how I can slice it:

1. How do I extract a 3D cluster for one specific time, i.e. 140?
2. From that extracted 3D cluster, how can I plot a 2D x-z cross-section for a specific y-position, i.e.45?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on basic numpy slicing: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html

> How do I extract a 3D cluster for one specific time, i.e. 140?

Just specify the time index, i.e. `data[:, :, :, 140]`. Be aware that Python indexing starts from 0.

> From that extracted 3D cluster, how can I plot a 2D x-z cross-section for a specific y-position, i.e.45?

You can acquire a 2D cross-section by a similar slicing operation, i.e. `cluster[:, 45, :]`. It can be plotted in various ways depending on the plotting library. `imshow()` from matplotlib might be one possibility.

Comment: Thank you so much for this great answer ! Now, slicing makes much more sense. It´s a very cool notation and method to extract data. One question: Would you know, if it is possible to flip the data? I am getting the x-z cross-section, but now I am wondering, how I could get the z-x cross. I tried the flip numpy function, but this just flips it left to right

Comment: To interchange dimensions of 2D array you can use the numpy transpose operation, i.e. as `my_2d_slice.T`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is much simpler than np.swapaxes that I just found. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Is your question about the data set (how does data categorize and how to get a 3D cluster at a specific time), or about the coding?

If it is about "How to get a cluster at a specific time" it means that your problem is about your particular dataset, which Stackoverflow is not a correct place for these types of question.

If it is about "coding" then define clearly your question and provide us with your code and the problem with it.

Based on your explanation, I think that for each time step, you have a complete set of xyz data, and so the solution is very strait.

Comment: Please post such comments into the comment section. Also, in my opinion, the question shows sufficient information to answer your question.

Comment: The question did not explain what method he used and why it does not work. In my point of view, the question was not clear.